# What is the best finish of a 4th place NFL team in their division

Tags: nfl

I was just wondering what the record wins (during the super bowl era) is of a 4th place team. For example, Washington commanders went 8-8-1 (.500) this year. Any team do any better to still come in 4th place in their division?

Answer (score 1):

There are (at least) three times a 4th place division team finished 8-8.

- 2007 Eagles: 8-8
- 2007 Texans: 8-8
- 2008 Saints: 8-8

This is since the 2002 realignment. I reckon there are better cases before then.